# DOS based software

Tags: reverse-engineering, dos

I've got some older software that was written for a customer.  The customer needs us to update it, or replicate it with modern software.  It's basically just an HMI that is sending commands out serially.  There is zero documentation on this machine.  I need to find out if there is some way we can decompile the software to see what functions it uses and what addresses it's buttons are sending instructions out on.  I am hoping some of the more seasoned programmers here on SE can point me in the right direction.  When I was programming in DOS, it was just BASIC or C applications that were very rudimentary.  Any advice is appreciated and I am perfectly willing to share this software.

Right now, I have a virtual machine set up with DOS.  When I try to run the software I get `System font loading error`.

Comment: Honestly, I would ignore the software for now and focus on understanding two things: 1) The hardware you need to interact with. 2) The data that gets sent/received over the serial line. I wouldn't look too much at the internals of the software until I understood those two things well.

Comment: That's what I was hoping to learn from the software.

Comment: An error like "System font loading error" when running an MS-DOS application suggests that the application wasn't installed correctly (eg. it's missing a font file.). Make sure you've copied the entire application, not just the .EXE, and you've copied any entries in the `CONFIG.SYS` and `AUTOEXEC.BAT` files it might need. But as David Schwartz suggests, if you want to update the software you might be better off obtaining the documentation for whatever its controlling and rewriting it from scratch.

Comment: Unfortunately there is zero documentation on this machine and the machine is about 2K mi from me :)  It's likely that I'll end up going down to TX to do a discovery on the machine, but I'd really like to go there fully loaded with what I can get now.          I thought it was strange but the original machine didn't have a `config.sys` or an `autoexec.bat`.  It wasn't hidden or anything.  There was, however, an `autoexec.bak` which indicates previous existence.  Bad luck.

Comment: You are making a difficult task much more difficult. The software will not do what it normally does without the hardware. So if you're trying to understand what the software normally does, you need the hardware.